# CouchDB Database Error

Tags: javascript, rest, http, couchdb, nosql

I am trying to access my couchDB database to perform simple get/post stuff.
My couchDB URL is : http://restify.iriscouch.com/

When I run the below code Nothing happens!

```
  var http = require( 'http' );
  http.get( 'http://restify.iriscouch.com/', function( res ) {
  console.log( res );
  });
```

But if I change the couchDB url to http://mikeal.iriscouch.com/ it works.
This url (http://mikeal.iriscouch.com/) is not mine I found it online from an example.

The below code works.

```
  var http = require( 'http' );
  http.get( 'http://mikeal.iriscouch.com/', function( res ) {
  console.log( res );
  });
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my Database?

Comment: Did you try hitting both URLs with a web browser to check they both returned some data?

Comment: @ChrisSnow  yes both return data when I access them from a browser. Ive been trying to solve this for days. I'll be grateful if you can help me solve this.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong (except that you don't handle errors with `on()`). The connection is just refused by the server. This is not the first time I see strange things on IrisCouch. You should either move to another hosting service or install your own instance of CouchDB.

Comment: @Aurélien currently I am trying to access my database through my node.js server. Heres a link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634342/couchdb-restify-node-js-and-node-couchdb). But when I access it without the node server with pure javascript and HTTP requests. It works.

Comment: IrisCouch probably requires a header sent by Ajax but not by Node.js. However it's not your job to fix IrisCouch bugs.

Comment: @Aurélien Thank you for replying. I think I'll try using MongoDB that probably will work better.

Comment: CouchDB is really a great piece of software. Its REST API is nearly perfect. It's the kind of environment that makes the developer smarter. Don't give up just because you had a problem with one hosting company. Have a try with [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com) or install your own CouchDB.